# Code or syntax behind documentation by useof .texi file type

Tags: text, documentation, document

How to understand the .texi file type?
The below is one sample preceding of long text in texi file

```
    @ifinfo
    @set dsq '@:'
    @set dsbq `@:`
    @end ifinfo
    @iftex
    @set dsq '{}'
    @set dsbq `{}`
    @end iftex
    @ifinfo
    @dircategory Utilities
    @end ifinfo

    @page
    This is a documentation by John

...
```

How to understand/ translate it to further (as some links there needs to be cleared)?

Comment: Requests for tutorials are off-topic here. As you are a noob, I'll point out the "block" of "code" delimited by `@ifinfo` and `@end ifinfo`. Any commands inside this block apply only to `.info` files, while the `@iftex` block aplies to `.tex` files. Both `info` and `tex` are text formatting programs. `tex` has generally been subseded by backwards compatible `latex` for academ/science papers.  The `info` program was created as a "better" `man page`. Do you know about typing `man cmd-of-interest`, ie. `man ls` , `man info`, `man tex`? (not all systems will have `tex` (or `latex` installed). ....

Comment: When someone tells you to RTFM (read the FINE manual), they are referring to the basic documentation system used by Unix, and later Linux. Try some of the `man` commands I have listed above. You should search for a tutorial about using/reading man pages as it is more than i can convey here in comments. If you're lucky, there will be a `man texti` entry that will help explain your sample file. Finally, the `info` program provides a more interactive version of `man` pages, allowing you to just (via links) to various parts of the `.info` page. Again, search for a tutorial. Good luck.

Comment: And now, here is my standard message to off-topic questions : StackOverflow is dedicated to helping **solve programming code problems** (not provide tutorials on how to read the code).  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , or possibly [unix.se]  but read their help section regarding on-topic questions. AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: By coincidence, this thread has some intersting information about `.texti`, `.tex` and `.info` formatting, but you'll have to dig thru a bunch of other stuff : https://groups.google.com/g/comp.unix.shell/c/0gloLrKqF6U  : Good luck.